# Cannot import dependency in Gradle plugin implementation

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to import material3 library into Gradle Kotlin-DSL implementation.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried importing it as the rest of imports in the plugin. Below is my plugin implementation

*AndroidLibraryComposeConventionPlugin.kt*

```
class AndroidLibraryComposeConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        with(target) {
            pluginManager.apply("com.android.library")
            val extension = extensions.getByType<LibraryExtension>()
            configureAndroidCompose(extension)
        }
    }

}
```

And in **libs.versions.toml** I have declared material3 dependency as following:

```
[libraries]
androidx-compose-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
```

But when I try to add this in the plugin as following:

```
"implementation"(libs.findLibrary("androidx-compose-material3").get())
```

or

```
add("implementation", libs.findLibrary("androidx-compose-material3").get())
```

I get an error that this dependency cannot be found.

libs is an extension created for this project and looks as following:

```
val Project.libs
    get(): VersionCatalog = extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")
```

Implementing it in plugin is crucial for me as I want to delegate importing dependencies to plugin, not build.gradle.kts itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is wasn't working was because material3 library in libs.versions.toml wasn't specified. That's weird behaviour, as I had compose BOM implemented, therefore version shouldn't be necessary to specify. I've reported issue to Google, maybe it's their fault.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295518536